# How to declare an interface inside class method?

Tags: java, interface, inner-classes, anonymous-function

I wrote the following class:

```
 public class Dog {
    private int age = 9;
    private String name = "newton";
    public String bark() {
        return "" + name+ " " + "bark";
    }
    public void assignCallback(ClassThatGetsCallback classThatGetCallback) {
        public interface Callback {
            public void callbackMethod();
        }

        classThatGetCallback.functionThatGetsCallback(new Callback() 
        {
            public void callbackMethod() {
                age =8;
                System.out.println(age);
                System.out.println(bark());
            }
        }); 
    }
}
```

I declared an interface with the name **Callback** inside the method **assignCallback**.
When trying to compile i'm getting the following error message:

> Dog.java.13: error: illegal start or expression
> public interface callback

What is the problem with my code?

Comment: You can't declare an interface within a method, you can move it out into the class or have it in its own file though

Comment: how would this be useful? to call `functionThatGetsCallback`, its parameter type would need to be `Callback`. But that is not available in `ClassThatGetsCallback`

Comment: @Clashsoft, i know this problem. I just want to understand if it is possible to write interface inside a method

Comment: @Eitanos30 Your question has already been answered.  No, you cannot declare an interface inside a method, but I can guarantee that whatever you're trying to achieve by doing that can be done in a better way.  You seem to have given us an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  Tell us what your real problem is, and we'll give you a better solution.

Comment: You seem generally confused when it comes to interface, classes and objects. You're trying to define a method inside the member initialization body (`new Callback() { ... }`), which isn't a thing. You should define methods in classes, not when you initialize it. Also, you can't call `new` on interfaces, you have to do it on classes.

Comment: @ShamPooSham, i implementing an anonymous class which implements the Callback interface.. It is very common in Java especially when adding a listener to a GUI element

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong, thanks a lot for the will to help but i really want to understand if it possible. I really don't have a specific problem i have to solve

Comment: @Eitanos30 Ah I see. C# Doesn't have anonymous classes. It would be more common to use lambda expressions. You could make `Callback` into a class where `callbackMethod` is a lambda expression with type `Expression<Func<TSource,TResult>>`